# How to combine two image features in a custom pytorch dataset?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to build a custom pytorch dataset with two images as features and one image as output.

Here is how the images are in the file system:

```
./feature1/image1.jpeg #64x64px
./feature2/image1.jpeg #64x64px
./output/image1.jpeg #64x64px
```

My objective is to create a neural network that will take as input

```
feature1 + feature2 => output.
```

What is the best way to create such a dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, what is best will depend on the nature of your data, model, and the relationship between the two images.

If your network is composed of simple linear layers you can simply concatenate the (flattened) tensors, since here ordering of features is arbitrary.

If it is a CNN (depending on the relationship of the images) it might make more sense to stack them in a 4th dimension (like frames of a video).

Comment: OP was asking about the dataset rather than the network architecture

Comment: @konstantinoskokos I'm aware of that.